# Spring Service doesn't answer

Tags: java, spring, rest, jax-rs

I have to create a new rest service, the problem is my service never answer and never logs.

On the the same app I have this following service class which works properly.
I mean on the browser (under this url http://localhost:8080/IMEL/resources/hello ) answers correctly "Hello from IMEL Rest service!"

```
package it.sella.imel.api.rest;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
@Path("/hello")
public class HelloService {

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello from IMEL Rest service!";
    }
}
```

While my new service doesn't log and responds (at this url http://localhost:8080/IMEL/resources/listapwg ) the following error "{"status":"EXPECTATION_FAILED","errorMessage":"HTTP 404 Not Found"}"

```
package src.main.java.it.sella.imel.api.rest;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.QueryParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.GenericEntity;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import it.sella.imel.api.model.TransazioneConstants;
import it.sella.imel.api.model.TransazioneSingola;
import it.sella.imel.db.DbManager;
import it.sella.imel.util.ImelConstants;
import it.sella.util.Log4Debug;
import it.sella.util.Log4DebugFactory;
import it.sella.imel.api.log.Logged;

@Service
@Logged
@Path("/listapwg")
public class ListaPWG {

    private static Log4Debug log4Debug = Log4DebugFactory.getLog4Debug(ListaPWG.class);
    

    @GET
    @Produces({MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
    public String helloListaPWG() {
        log4Debug.debug("sono in helloListaPWG GET");
        return "Hello from IMEL Rest service!";
    }
    
    @POST
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public Response fetchListaPWG(@QueryParam("dataQuadratura") String dataQuadratura, @Context UriInfo uriInfo) {
        log4Debug.debug("sono in fetchListaPWG POST");
        ... do some other stuff ...
        return Response.status(Response.Status.OK).entity(entity).build();

    }
}
```

obviously maven compiles correctly...

the only difference I see is the Logged class, but within or without, in any case it won't work, that's why I don't think that is the problem.

```
package it.sella.imel.api.log;

import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME;

import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

import javax.ws.rs.NameBinding;

@NameBinding
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
public @interface Logged {

}
```

Comment: I doubt that `package src.main.java.it.sella.imel.api.rest;` is the actual package you want... Remove the `src.main.java` part and try again.

Comment: Deinum, that was! Thank you, u don't know how much time I lost behind it! F eclipse!